# A new user of 'Authors' role unable to view list of news items

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-3x

In my Sitefinity 3.7 website, I created a new user which is a member of the 'Authors' role. When the user tries to view the list of news items (../Sitefinity/Admin/Modules.aspx?module=News), the following exception is thrown:

===========================================================================
Server Error in '/' Application.

---

A required control was not found in the template for "~/ControlTemplates/News/NewsItemsList.ascx". The control must be assignable form type "System.Web.UI.WebControls.IButtonControl" and must have ID "groupOperationsLink". 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Telerik.Cms.Web.UI.TemplateException: A required control was not found in the template for "~/ControlTemplates/News/NewsItemsList.ascx". The control must be assignable form type "System.Web.UI.WebControls.IButtonControl" and must have ID "groupOperationsLink".

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

===========================================================================

Can you please recommend a fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin will need to make sure that the Authors role has permissions on the News Module. Make sure the appropriate permissions are set for the Author role, view, create, etc.

Permission are in the left column once you navigate to the news module.
Once these permission are set you should be good to go!