# Onclick event in anchor tag not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, onclick, anchor, internet-explorer-10

I've an anchor in an Asp.Net user control. I've wired some code to the onclick event. For some reason in Internet Explorer 10, the event is not firing. The markup is structured as

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor" onclick="myFunction();return false;"></a>
```

where myFunction is a simple JavaScript function. For those who want to see the page in action, here is the link:

http://alt.thedominion.ca/TheBrokerAdvantage/LocateABroker.aspx

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The link is empty, you must put something there to make it appear and be clickable.

Comment: Which link on your page is not working?

Comment: jsfiddle is currently crashing my IE10 (no surprise here) so can't try and reproduce, but I'm 99% sure that syntax work just fine in IE10.

Comment: @dreamweiver - The magnifying glass next to the postal code box; It is actually an anchor link.

Comment: `<a id="brokerSearchButton" onclick="doSearch();return false;" href="#"></a>` this is the anchor tag which is not working right. why dont you change it as `<a id="brokerSearchButton" onclick="return doSearch();" href="#"></a>` and add a **return false** to the last of the **doSearch()** in JS.

Comment: I tried doing that. It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your server side code, not the browser or JavaScript.

If you check the JavaScript console in IE10 you will see the following error when clicking the link:

> SCRIPT5009: 'ValidatorValidate' is undefined

Which points to the second line in the function:

```
function doSearch() {
    var regExValidate = document.getElementById("ctl00_BrokerSearchMiddle_ctl00_ValidPostalCode");
    ValidatorValidate(regExValidate);

    var postalCode = $find("ctl00_BrokerSearchMiddle_ctl00_PostalCode").get_value();

    if (regExValidate.isvalid && postalCode.indexOf("e.g") == -1) {
        document.location.href = "?postalCode=" + postalCode;
    }
}
```

This means the `onclick` is working just fine, you simply have JS error.

Now the question is why `ValidatorValidate` exists in other browsers (even IE9) but not in IE10. Well, in IE10 [the script where it's being defined](http://alt.thedominion.ca/ScriptResource.axd?d=buq2yireoeeF1nkyw4eh1dqjZ21i8mdtErn7Vh_89mtakBr_CeeaboPnjmR_x7zAxO_8cTar3v43J6QH_Ju0Zw2&t=ffffffffd80ff90f) is not included, meaning the server never put the line `<script src="...">` with that URL as part of the output to the browser.

I can only guess that the server side code is checking the browser version and according to that include certain scripts. Check that code and get rid of such things as it's never a good idea.

After some research I found what's going on. You are using Sitefinity version 3.7 to build your site (according to [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15526236/447356)) and as officially [stated here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/community-forums/about-telerik/sitefinity-3-7-bug-on-ie-10.aspx):

> I want to inform you that unfortunately Sitefinity 3.7 does not support Internet Explorer 10 and your Sitefinity 3.7 might not work properly with this browser version. Apologies for the inconvenience

You will have to upgrade your Sitefinity if you want IE10 support.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works on every major browser (I just tested it on IE10, IE9, Chrome 26.0.1410.64, and the latest firefox release).

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor" onclick="myFunction();return false;">click me</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    alert("Anchor was clicked");
}
</script>
```

In other words, your syntax is fine, but the anchor tag simply will not appear without inner text unless you use CSS to force a width and height.

**CSS option:**

```
a{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

## [Working CSS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kT8jZ/1/)