# ValidatorValidate method in JavaScript not working for ie10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

Does anyone use the JavaScript `ValidatorValidate` function to control their asp.net validators on the client side?

Have been using it for years, but have noticed that with IE10, I now get this javascript error:

`SCRIPT5009: 'ValidatorValidate' is undefined`

It's like the relevant javascript libraries aren't included with IE10 - has anyone come across this before?  Is there a way of including the relevant code?

**Update**
Just to update, I thought `ValidatorValidate()` was a purely JS function, but have discovered it's generated by ASP.net.

Thanks

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149131/onclick-event-in-anchor-tag-not-working-in-ie10

Comment: Hi.  I already saw that post and I don't use Sitefinity, so the solution doesn't seem to apply here. Thanks anyway though

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: Take a look at the source code that is downloaded by the browser. It should contain the `ValidatorValidate` function. If it doesn't, then compare it with the same page downloaded by another browser, and see what the difference is; try to work out why IE10 isn't downloading that function. If it is there, then maybe it's got a syntax error that IE10 can't cope with. Try examining the code of the function (and the code around it) directly.

Comment: @Yuriy - I'm using .net 2 on windows server 2003. Yep, your answer below is definitely the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely .NET FrameWork in your application is not aware of IE10 and downgrades it to a lower browser capabilites. The solution is to either apply one of the following hotfixes on WebServer hosting the app:

- .NET 4 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088
- .NET 2.0:

  - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100 for Win7 SP1/Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Vista/Server 2008, Windows XP/Server 2003
  - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565 for Win7/Windows Server 2008 R2 RTM

If this is not an option, you can make you application aware of IE10, by adding [browser definition file](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/App_BrowsersUpdate.zip) to its `APP_Browsers` folder.

Ref: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: Hi Yuriy, just found that exact information just this second! Have been on to the administrators to add the hotfix, so hopefully we can get a solution.  When I tested other applications, `PageRequestManager` also couldn't be found which caused a lot of other issues for me.  Thanks for your assistance